# Cannot find data by ID from MySql using Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound #customer with that id cannot be found
     redirect_to action: :index
  end

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound #customer with that id cannot be found
    redirect_to action: :index
  end
```

Now the problem is it is not finding my data which exists in database. When i put new data then it works fine but only when I need to update or show that data on user requirement. Then it says record not found but at the same time the new input data can be put into data base as I told you before.

Comment: have you tried executing the queries on rails console and seen what results are being displayed

Comment: give a try like @item = Item.find(params[:id].to_i)

Comment: i updated the values ucing rails console but i was not able to do so using code....i also tried this @item = Item.find(params[:id].to_i) but nothing is changed....i am stuck here please help????????

Comment: are you sure your controller is getting the correct parameters. Can you post the rails server log of this request?

Comment: Please show us the show.html.erb file of the spiecific controler. May be you are not correctly passing the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Show Item</h1>
<p>
  <strong>Mobile: </strong>
  <%= @item.mobile %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Company: </strong>
  <%= @item.company %>
</p>
```

this is show.html.erb file code.

Console output:

Started GET "/items.%23%3CItem::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb515b124%3E" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-04 23:43:09 +0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by ItemsController#index as 
  Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`
  Rendered items/index.html.erb within layouts/application (13.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 309ms (Views: 291.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)